# URL Separation in Flask

Tags: python, rest, url, flask, restful-url

I am listening to a `Flask` URL of the form,

```
http://example.com:8080/v1/api?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3&param4=value4
```

Now, I want to achieve `URL` separation of the parameters in either of the below forms, (**ForwardSlash**)

```
http://example.com:8080/v1/api?param1=value1&param2=value2/parameters?param3=value3&param4=value4
```

OR (**Semicolon**)

```
http://example.com:8080/v1/api?param1=value1&param2=value2;parameters?param3=value3&param4=value4
```

I know these are not clean `URLs` and need to be avoided, but such is the usecase.

I am currently listening to the URL as,

```
@app.route('/v1/api', methods=['GET','POST'])
def api_call():
    #....code for listening ...
```

How do I modify my code to get the `URL` separation as desired above?

I understand I am not following good principles of URL formation or other design principles, this is a use case requirement and am stuck on achieving this through Flask.

Comment: Could you clarify what the question is? Do you just want to know how to parse the URLs above? If so, to what desired result?

Comment: There's nothing specific to Flask to make this work. You'll need to build and parse the query string yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing all the values as query params, can you use form-post to achieve this? You can pass an object using this method and will give you more flexibility on the type of data-structure that you want to achieve.